# Count total items that are link with others in vb.net epplus

Tags: excel, vb.net, epplus

Hello so i have a question
i have this excel file and i need to count the total of variables but this ones are dependable on other columns in excel.
like this:

| SHIP | TYPE | DUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MOL BEN | CASA | 900 |
| MOL BEN | CASA | 901 |
| MOL BEN | PANL | 922 |
| MOL BEN | CASA | 934 |
| MOL BEN | CASA | 942 |
| MSN AIN | PANL | 1530 |
| MSN AIN | PANL | 1540 |
| MSN AIN | CASA | 1544 |
| MSN AIN | CASA | 1544 |

so i would need to say in the total that the ship MOL BEN in the type CASA has 4 DUS items and in the type PANL has 1 DUS item.

In the ship MSN AIN in the type CASA has 2 DUS items and in the type PANL has 2 DUS items.

In the excel, the ship could be anything so i can't use the names to do validations

in the type it would always be either CASA OR PANL

any ideas in how to do this in vb.net using epplus?  for example i use Workbook.Worksheets to fill the excel in other programs that i made thanks in advance

Comment: Does the solution have to use EPPlus?

Comment: i guess not, but im using it for everything else in code

Comment: It seems that I just answered this question. Did you delete a question?

Comment: @JOHNDoe  Why not accept answers that ... answers your questions?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any way to enumerate rows in EPPlus during my quick look (I don't use it for reading, only writing) let's write an interator that will make the sheet into an enumerable list of named ValueTuples; it will make them easier to work with and they will group implicitly being value types:

```
    Private Iterator Function SheetIterator(w As ExcelWorksheet, fromRow As Integer, toRow As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of (Shp As String, Typ As String, Dus As String))
        For row = fromRow To toRow
            Yield (Shp:=w.Cells(row, 1).Text, Typ:=w.Cells(row, 2).Text, Dus:=w.Cells(row, 3).Text)
        Next
    End Function
```

Now you have a device that enumerates a sheet, and returns valuetuples (objects that have a `Shp`, `Typ` and `Dus` property of the values in your rows. This means you can do something like:

```
SheetIterator(x, 1, 4) _                 
  .GroupBy(Function(z) (z.Shp, z.Typ)) _ 
  .Select(Function(g) (g.Key.Shp, g.Key.Typ, Ct:=g.Count()))
```

The lines do:

1. It runs the function, which will enumerate the sheet
2. It groups the returned objects, grouping by Shp/Typ, so you get an object that has a Key of e.g. `("MOL BEN", "CASA")` and is itself a list of every object that has those pair of values, so it's a list of 4 objects. The hardest thing to get to terms with in `GroupBy` is that the return is like a `List(Of EnhancedList(Of Something))`
3. We Select, which operates on the outer list. Each entry in the outer list is aliased as `g`, and it has a Key property that is what we grouped on (an object representing Shp/Typ), and it itself is a list of all the objects that share that Shp/Typ; we don't do anything with that list other than Coount it

The output is hence another object that has a Shp, Typ and Ct (count) properties, and the sequence as a whole will end up looking like e.g.

```
("MOL BEN", "CASA", 4)
("MOL BEN", "PANL", 2)
...
```